# Getting a Article/BlogPosting Rich Result in Google Search without using AMP

Tags: google-search, structured-data, amp

Has anyone ever had any success with getting a non-AMP-encoded page to appear in Google search as a Rich Result using either the Article or BlogPosting Schema.org Item Type? I tried with numerous different blog posts to get a Rich Result in Google searches that the posts rank Position #1 for but have never had any luck. Each time I made sure to include all of the [required and recommended types](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article). Even after referencing the URLs in a Schema.org Carousel placed in the source code of the blog homepage - [as suggested](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel) - the blog posts' pages never appear in Google results with their associated image or in a news carousel.

Google claims in [1](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article) that AMP isn't required for an Article/Blogposting-encoded page to be featured as a Rich Result, but again I have never seen it happen. Can anyone cite such an example?

Answer (score 1):

Searching Google for "install ram" has an article carousel.  Two of the articles in it are not AMP and have no AMP version.

- **on Windows 10** and **on desktop**: https://www.pcworld.com/article/2957195/how-to-install-new-memory-in-your-pc.html -- Not AMP but has an AMP version
- **on laptop**: https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-install-ram-in-your-laptop/ -- Not AMP
- **in iMac**: https://www.wikihow.com/Install-RAM-in-an-iMac  -- Not AMP but has an AMP version
- **in Macbook Pro**: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165 -- Not AMP

I verified these with [Google's AMP test](https://search.google.com/test/).

Comment: I think I was able to replicate what you saw - is this it?: https://i.imgur.com/tGY7xYp.jpg

But is a Featured Snippet the same thing as a rich result for a non-AMP page with Article structured data? I'm not sure they are - Google has a separate answer for Featured Snippets: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9351707?p=featured_snippets&hl=en&visit_id=637137869615852514-4174984759&rd=1

What's the difference? Well, maybe Google considers the page that gets a Featured Snippet sort of an authority while a rich result for an Article page could just be a topical inclusion.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm seeing.  From https://moz.com/blog/exploring-carousel-featured-snippet

Comment: Thank you for confirming. Still, that Moz article doesn't even mention structured data or Schema.org. hmm...

Comment: What type of rich result do you actually have in mind?   If you are talking about the "Top Stories" news carousel, I believe that one is powered by Google News which has its own set of requirements: https://moz.com/blog/how-to-get-into-google-news

Comment: See, this is where it gets confusing. I want to call them simply (article) rich results because "rich results" is the closest category I've seen inside Search Console: https://i.imgur.com/SdjapvE.png
That list of categories appears under the Search Appearance report, of course. I've never seen an Articles enhancement report and I don't believe they exist: https://search.google.com/u/2/search-console/articles?resource_id=sc-domain%3APUTYOURDOMAIN.com&hl=en

Comment: They featured snippet carousel is the only rich result that is based on the article schema as far as I know.

Comment: Right, me too! But since Google Dev says a non-AMP page with Article data can appear "as **a rich result in a rich result list**", that includes other possible arrangements besides a Featured Snippet and Google News carousel. For instance, a website like Microsoft's gets a "Latest from" rich result carousel if one googles "microsoft" and none of the pages in that carousel are or have AMP pages _but_ they do employ the creativeWork Item Type. I want that for my site! :-/